# Remove - from number

Tags: php, sql

I need to remove Hyphen from numbers and I cant find the function that does this. I know I have used it before Somewhere but I cant remember.

+123-567-896

need +123-567896 like this

Comment: and what did you try and research before coming to Stackoverflow?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And, explain better your logic.  Your result set still has a hyphen, so your question is unclear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff not sure database is relevant here..

Comment: @treyBake Gordon is mentioning it because of the SQL tag's description: _"Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data,  >>> and a tag for the DBMS implementation <<<"_

Comment: @icecub true, but unless this is to be done via SQL, I think the SQL tag and any subsequent database tag redundant

Comment: Duped as there are hundreds of examples of how to do this on Stack. I picked the first of several, you should be able to make the code work for you from any of those examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strrpos()` to find the last occurrence of a certain character in a string. So in this case your hyphen. You can then use the `substr_replace()` function to replace one character with `''` (empty string) on the position of your `-`

```
$tel = '+123-567-896';    

echo substr_replace($tel,'', strrpos($tel, '-'), 1);
```

Will give you:

```
+123-567896
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/VfFGh

Answer (score -2):

You can use this function `str_replace('-','','+123-567-896')`

Comment: According to the example, this is wrong. You can clearly see only the last hyphen should be removed, not all of them.

Comment: @icecub .There is nothing mentioned in the Question that only last Hyphen should be removed?Am i right?

Comment: Nope, you're not right. Look at the examples the OP supplies. *"need +123-567896 like this"*

Comment: _"+123-567-896"_ => _"need +123-567896 like this"_ - He's clearly telling you here how the end result should look like

Comment: ohh Sorry for that.I didn't notice at the last line.

Comment: You don't have to appologise for trying to help someone. Better to try and fail than not participate at all. Just learn from your mistake and improve next time :)